# Parsing HTML element into parts

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to parse the following code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable" style="table-layout: fixed;max-width:100% !important;width: 100% !important;min-width: 100% !important;">
```

Essentially what I need is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <table
    [1] => border="0"
    [2] => cellpadding="0"
    [3] => cellspacing="0"
    [4] => height="100%"
    [5] => width="100%"
    [6] => id="bodyTable"
    [7] => style="table-layout: fixed;max-width:100% !important;width: 100% !important;min-width: 100% !important;
)
```

However when doing this with a simple `explode(" ", $str);` I'm getting the "style" split up too, is there a simple way to parse this and loop through it?

Comment: remove the spaces from inside your `style` attribute if you are using space as a delimiter in `explode()`.

Comment: You could also try regular expressions if you're just looking for a quick hacky solution.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: @kooKooDoneSlapHisWife how would you suggest doing this? another problem I have is that there might be a class="v1 v2.." that I'd like to retain but have explode in the right order.

Comment: @dan08 could you suggest a regex expression?

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius Use `preg_match_all` and this regex: https://regex101.com/r/rR1bX0/2 ... I do not condone this, but I couldn't resist :)

Comment: Thank you, helped me out a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = array ();
$str = '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable" style="table-layout: fixed;max-width:100% !important;width: 100% !important;min-width: 100% !important;">';
$str_arr = explode (' style', $str);
$result = explode (' ', $str_arr[0]);
array_push($result, 'style'.$str_arr [1]);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```